# Learning Ethereum for a Python developer

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have been developing in Python for three years. Recently, I became obsessed with the technology of Ethereum and wanted to work on Ethereum. I learned solidity and hardhat. But I think wanting to work on the blockchain is not enough. Then I started to look at the source code of go-ethereum recently, but the source code is really too complicated. My idea is to keep reading the source code. If I can make an article on the blockchain first, I believe it will be more convenient to read the source code.

So I would like to ask all seniors, what technology should I learn so that I can do blockchain first?

Comment: If you have such experience in python, you might want to have a look at Brownie (Python based development tool)

Comment: Brownie is no longed maintained, ApeWorX has more or less replaced it https://www.apeworx.io/

Answer (score 2):

Some technologies you need to understand is

- Smart contracts programming (Vyper, Solidity)
- Interacting with the blockchain from Python (web3.py, ApeWorX)

Good starting points to learn blockchain development are included on Ethereum Foundation website:

- [Ethereum for Python developers](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/python/#python-community-contributors)
- [Smart contract languages](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/languages/)

Also, I was recently hosting [the PyChain 2022 conference](https://www.pychain.org/). We have [a YouTube playlist of Python blockchain development videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HOU3z0LoDg&list=PLdUZql_QHnoWAX1uBZ9sLvDYneVyW6Hgc) with a lot of learning material.